# jQuery script to add class after date reached

Tags: jquery, class, date

I have a list with multiple items. Each item has a date. I'm now looking for a jQuery script that adds a class to the element, if the current date is equal or greater to the date of the element.

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="entry" data-date="2018-09-25">
        Some content here
    </li>
    <li class="entry" data-date="2018-09-27">
        Some content here
    </li>
    <li class="entry" data-date="2018-10-05">
        Some content here
    </li>
</ul>
```

So let's pretent it's September 27th, then it should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="entry additional-class" data-date="2018-09-25">
        Some content here
    </li>
    <li class="entry additional-class" data-date="2018-09-27">
        Some content here
    </li>
    <li class="entry" data-date="2018-10-05">
        Some content here
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried it with this code:

```
    $(function() {
  var date = new Date(),
    currentDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
  $(".entry").each(function() {
    var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
    if (specifiedDate >= currentDate) {
      $(this).addClass('past');
    }
  });
});
```

Many thanks!

Comment: what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Comment: I have added the code I've tried above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the element and use an if statement to compare the dates, then add the class to those that comply with your requirement.

```
let todayDate = new Date();
$("li").each(function(){
   let liDate = new Date($(this).attr("data-date"));
   if(liDate < todayDate){
       $(this).addClass("additional-class");
   }
});
```

This might work.